# How to get IP used by sendto function?

Tags: sockets, winapi, ip

When the sender has multiple network cards, this function `sendto` chooses random ip to send the packet.
So get the ip address used by `sendto`?
Code:

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
sendto(fd, buf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
```

Comment: Your routing table determines which NIC, you can force it with socket options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't choose a random IP.  It uses the OS's routing table to decide which local IP has the best chance of routing the data to the destination address.  However, there is no way to query which IP `sendto()` actually chose to use.  You could access the OS's routing table directly and try to figure it out manually, but the better option is to just `bind()` the socket to the specific IP that you want `sendto()` to use as the sending IP, eg:

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in localaddr;
memset(&localaddr, 0, sizeof(localaddr));
localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1"); // the desired local IP

bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&localaddr, sizeof(localaddr));

sendto(fd, buf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
```